# How to create list of string elements

Tags: python-2.7

I need method to get any type of text in list so it looks like this:
`L = ['@', '$'. ')']` etc. I couldn't do it because text contains all special characters like brackets, `#` etc.

Example of text:

```
(&_+][&_@)$&$&^[_$(++$^}]&^^*(+*!&#_$]*+@!]+{%^_*+!&}@$!#^{+_#([+@(((*+)[()__}(^
@)](+[$*_(]*$[[&@^(_*#(*&!^{+]_%i)_)^[}@]#]%#@+^+[%{_*{!)}#$@#)_$!_(!*+#}%%}+$&$[
%&]!{{%*_!*}&)}$**_{*!#%[[#]!](^^$![#[[*}%(_#^^!%))!_^@)@**@}}(%%{#*%@(((]^%^![&
}!)$]&($)@](+(#{$)_%^%_^^#][{*[)%}+[##(##^{$}^]#&(&*{)%)&][&{]&#]}[[^^&[!#}${@_(
@}&$[[%]_&$+)$!%{(}$^$}*
```

Problem is that I need to make program that will search this kind of text to get letters, but I can't create list of this characters.

Comment: look at escape characters, [link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: If you just want a list of all the characters just set it to a string and then do `list(stringvar)` I am having a hard time understanding what you mean by your question. Do you want all char's to be in list or do you want to filter out some characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get achieve like this

```
>>> text = """(&_+][&_@)$&$&^[_$(++$^}]&^^*(+*!&#_$]*+@!]+{%^_*+!&}@$!#^{+_#([+@(((*+)[()__}(^
... @)](+[$*_(]*$[[&@^(_*#(*&!^{+]_%i)_)^[}@]#]%#@+^+[%{_*{!)}#$@#)_$!_(!*+#}%%}+$&$[
... %&]!{{%*_!*}&)}$**_{*!#%[[#]!](^^$![#[[*}%(_#^^!%))!_^@)@**@}}(%%{#*%@(((]^%^![&
... }!)$]&($)@](+(#{$)_%^%_^^#][{*[)%}+[##(##^{$}^]#&(&*{)%)&][&{]&#]}[[^^&[!#}${@_(
... @}&$[[%]_&$+)$!%{(}$^$}*"""
>>> L = list()
>>> for character in text:
...     L.append(character)
... 
>>> L
['(', '&', '_', '+', ']', '[', '&', '_', '@', ')', '$', '&', '$', '&', '^', '[', '_', '$', '(', '+', '+', '$', '^', '}', ']', '&', '^', '^', '*', '(', '+', '*', '!', '&', '#', '_', '$', ']', '*', '+', '@', '!', ']', '+', '{', '%', '^', '_', '*', '+', '!', '&', '}', '@', '$', '!', '#', '^', '{', '+', '_', '#', '(', '[', '+', '@', '(', '(', '(', '*', '+', ')', '[', '(', ')', '_', '_', '}', '(', '^', '\n', '@', ')', ']', '(', '+', '[', '$', '*', '_', '(', ']', '*', '$', '[', '[', '&', '@', '^', '(', '_', '*', '#', '(', '*', '&', '!', '^', '{', '+', ']', '_', '%', 'i', ')', '_', ')', '^', '[', '}', '@', ']', '#', ']', '%', '#', '@', '+', '^', '+', '[', '%', '{', '_', '*', '{', '!', ')', '}', '#', '$', '@', '#', ')', '_', '$', '!', '_', '(', '!', '*', '+', '#', '}', '%', '%', '}', '+', '$', '&', '$', '[', '\n', '%', '&', ']', '!', '{', '{', '%', '*', '_', '!', '*', '}', '&', ')', '}', '$', '*', '*', '_', '{', '*', '!', '#', '%', '[', '[', '#', ']', '!', ']', '(', '^', '^', '$', '!', '[', '#', '[', '[', '*', '}', '%', '(', '_', '#', '^', '^', '!', '%', ')', ')', '!', '_', '^', '@', ')', '@', '*', '*', '@', '}', '}', '(', '%', '%', '{', '#', '*', '%', '@', '(', '(', '(', ']', '^', '%', '^', '!', '[', '&', '\n', '}', '!', ')', '$', ']', '&', '(', '$', ')', '@', ']', '(', '+', '(', '#', '{', '$', ')', '_', '%', '^', '%', '_', '^', '^', '#', ']', '[', '{', '*', '[', ')', '%', '}', '+', '[', '#', '#', '(', '#', '#', '^', '{', '$', '}', '^', ']', '#', '&', '(', '&', '*', '{', ')', '%', ')', '&', ']', '[', '&', '{', ']', '&', '#', ']', '}', '[', '[', '^', '^', '&', '[', '!', '#', '}', '$', '{', '@', '_', '(', '\n', '@', '}', '&', '$', '[', '[', '%', ']', '_', '&', '$', '+', ')', '$', '!', '%', '{', '(', '}', '$', '^', '$', '}', '*']
```